# VueJs - Need to increment the percentage in progress bar when the record is created using Axios.post

Tags: axios, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I need to show a progress bar when a record in saved using VueJs. I have brought circular progress bar. Now, I don't know how to calculate the percentage for saving record. I am using Axios.post to save the record.

Adding code for progress bar:

```
<v-dialog v-if="progressBar" v-model="progressBar" max-width="100" >
                    <v-flex xs10 class="mx-auto progressbar">
                        <v-progress-circular 
                            :rotate="360"
                            :size="100"
                            :width="7"
                            :value="value"
                            indeterminate
                            color="primary" >
                            {{ value }}
                        </v-progress-circular>
                    </v-flex>                   
                </v-dialog>
```

Post method:

```
payload.context.contentHeader = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }                
            }   
    Axios.post(payload.createActions, payload.record, payload.context.contentHeader).then(record => {
                let result = record.data, context = payload.context;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "onUploadProgress" callback, as follows:

```
axios.post( '/my-url',
      [other parameters],
      onUploadProgress: function( progressEvent ) {
        this.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total ) * 100 );
      }.bind(this)
    }
```

Be sure to replace "this.uploadPercentage" with the correct variable.

Here is a good resource on the topic:

https://serversideup.net/file-upload-progress-indicator-with-axios-and-vuejs/

Comment: Do i need to give like this: Axios.post(payload.createActions, payload.record, payload.context.contentHeader,onUploadProgress: function( progressEvent ) {
            this.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total ) * 100 ));
          })                                                                                        It showing some error

Comment: The example assumes that you have an "uploadPercentage" variable.  Replace "this.uploadPercentage" with whatever variable you have - perhaps it is this.progressBar.

Comment: Hi, I have given like this:Axios.post(payload.createActions, payload.record, payload.context.contentHeader,{
            onUploadProgress: function( progressEvent ) {
            context.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total ) * 100 ));
          }}).then(record => {
            let result = record.data, context = payload.context;
    }                                                                                 But te progress bar is showing 0

Comment: I see the problem and fixed it.  You need to add ".bind(this)" to the end of the callback function.  I have corrected this in the above post.

Comment: Hi, This works ...Thankyou.. Is it possible to call this onUploadProgres based on a condition

Comment: I don't think so, but why not just put the condition inside the onUploadProgress function?